# How to implement an Eff-like monad without foreign interface

Tags: purescript

I am interested in implementing something like [Freer Monads, more Extensible Effects](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/more.pdf) in PureScript, but using rows rather than an open union (I suppose it is possible).

However, I wasn't able to define a kind without `foreign import`. I want to be able to do something like:

```
kind X
data Y :: # X -> Type -> Type

data Z :: X
```

Is that something I can do or should I look for another approach?

Comment: I don't understand the intended meaning of the `Log` type.

Comment: It represents an effect of logging a string, and the interpretation of that will be given later by a handler (eg, logging said string to IO or appending it to a file).

Comment: If you want to keep `Log` in a type row, then it cannot have a string in it. PureScript is not dependently typed, so types cannot have values embedded.

Comment: Alright, but how do I say that `Z` is of kind `X`? (Edited `Log` to be `Z` now)

Comment: You say `data Z :: X`

Comment: well, it doesn't work. It says it's a parsing error. :(

Comment: Well, of course you also need to prefix everything with `foreign import`. You can't declare a `kind` like that, it has to be `foreign import`. And so do all `data` which are not `:: Type`.

Comment: My question was exactly if there is a way to do that without `foreign import` :( But thanks, don't wanna write the thing in javascript.

Comment: That's a rather strange question. This is the syntax of the language, you can't use a different syntax. And why would you want to?

Comment: I know I can't use a different syntax than the one available. I would want to define a kind, types of that kind and inhabit such types, and most importantly without touching javascript for that. I couldn't find any documentation about kinds in purescript, except for a couple of lines that claim "user-defined" kinds -- what made me assume it were possible without `foreign import`.

Comment: What I still don't see is what exactly prevents you from doing what you described.

Comment: I'd love to have pointers on how to do that then.

Comment: What prevents you? What's the problem that you've encountered?

Comment: I don't know how to define a type of a specific kind and inhabit, for instance something like `data Z :: Type -> X = Zz a`.

Comment: Only types of kind `Type` can be inhabited. You cannot inhabit a type of any other kind.

Comment: I guess that answers your question on what prevents me.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need to inhabit non-`Type` types with values in order to do that.

Comment: Alright, as I saw from purescript-eff and related libs all function are defined as foreign import and a type of certain kind magically appears in the type signature. I don't want to define all my effects/effect functions as foreign import/in javascript, I want to define them in purescript. Do you have any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found out an implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nathan Faubion has an implementation of extensible effects, called [`purescript-run`](https://github.com/natefaubion/purescript-run), using row polymorphism, variants and proxies.